# I don't understand this trigonometry question.

Tags: trigonometry

[This](http://gyazo.com/eba2e46da0d2bae483ebe9ec5a1a3a51.png) is the link of the picture:

[image]

$AC = 4$
$BD = 20$ (Bigger than $A C \times 5$ so $5 \times 4 = 20$)

Found:

$BCD= 157.38^\circ$

$ABC \text{ or } ADC = 22.26^\circ$

Question:

Find the ratio between the length of the long diagonal of the rhombus volume.

What does that mean?
Thanks.

Correct answer is: 1:2.038 OR 0.4907

Comment: Do you mean *area*? Well, find the area and divide by the long diagonal (the length of which is actually used to calculate the area...)

Comment: Nope, I mean a Scope

Comment: I mean: Circumference. Translated version of this.

Comment: When drawing a problem like this you should try to make it at least approximately to-scale. A lot of answers will be more intuitive when you can see the differences in lengths and angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  You can evaluate the side of the rhombus from the Pythagorean theorem and the lengths of $BC,BE$ and you have the long diagonal is $BD=20$, so take the ratio.

Comment: I have just done the exact same thing, and I am getting 1.96 instead of 1:2.036 OR o.4907

Comment: Each side is $\sqrt {104} \approx 10.2$ so the circumference is about $40.8$.  $\frac {20}{4\sqrt {104}}\approx 0.4903$

Comment: I am getting0.935 instead of 0.49, why?

Comment: @user73230:  I don't know without seeing your work.  Maybe you put the $4$ in the numerator?

Comment: Sorry, not 1.9, I am getting 0.935, I did 20 /4√104

Comment: @user73230:  I don't see how.  If you replace $\sqrt {104}$ with $10$, which is not far off, you get $\frac {20}{40}=0.5$  I have a little bigger term in the denominator, so the answer should be a little smaller, which it is.

Comment: I have just done 20 / 4 10-−−√ and got 2.

Comment: Then you are not using your calculator correctly.  I think my previous comment shows it is very close to $0.5$.  [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=20%2F%284+sqrt%28104%29%29) is the Alpha output.  In your last comment you clearly lost a $4$, but I don't understand the keypresses and where the parentheses are.  Try $sqrt(104)*4/20$ and then invert it.

Comment: Thanks I now got it, thanks a llot!!